# How are kernel modules in /etc/modules determined (because one of mine fails to load)?

Tags: 12.04, server, kernel, upstart, modules

I was trying to setup lm-sensors ([Community Guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SensorInstallHowto)) and when I get to step 4 (sudo service module-init-tools restart) the service fails to start.

In /var/log/upstart/module-init-tools.log I get an entry: "FATAL: Module rtc not found."

Here's my /etc/modules:

```
# /etc/modules: kernel modules to load at boot time.
#
# This file contains the names of kernel modules that should be loaded
# at boot time, one per line. Lines beginning with "#" are ignored.

loop
lp
rtc
# Generated by sensors-detect on Wed Jul 31 15:15:33 2013
# Chip drivers
coretemp
w83627ehf
```

So my question is, 1) How are those first few modules determined and is rtc there by mistake? and 2) Can I safely remove rtc from the list since it's not being found anyways?

Comment: There is a bug filed for the missing module: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/kmod/+bug/1240935 .

Answer (score 0):

The tool that loads modules in kernel is 'modprobe'.

From its manpage,

> 'modprobe' looks in the module directory /lib/modules/$(uname -r) for
>   all modules and other files, and also the optional configuration files
>   in the '/etc/modprobe.d'. 'modprobe' also find modules kernel from command
>   line, in the form of module.option and blacklists in the form of
>   modprobe.blacklist=module.

For a detailed description of what 'rtc' does, the link is this [one](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/rtc.txt). This is not strictly needed to the system, but only to some app. Perhaps your system does not have such app and it is safe to remove.